# Do java.awt.Robot and java.awt.event.KeyEvent support mousekeys?

Tags: java

I'm making a little script I use mouse keys to save me some time with my work. I can use the mouse keys properly properly and fine. But when using `java.awt.Robot` and `java.awt.event.KeyEvent`, the mousekeys are essentially ignored and instead the program presses the literal key.

If the program were to call `robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_MULTIPLY)` and mousekeys were enabled, the program outputs the asterisk instead of changing the Numpad 5 key to right click as would happen when doing this manually.

Is this intended? If so, why does Java not support this, or more specifically `java.awt`?

EDIT: Referring to Windows Mouse Keys from the Ease of Access Center

Comment: meant to type `robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SLASH)`, which would cause Numpad 5 key to left click

Comment: Are you talking about the Windows Mouse Keys in the Ease of Access in the Control Panel?

Comment: yeah, sorry should've mentioned that in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [java.awt.Robot Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) "...the events are generated in the platform's native input queue". The implementation of the Ease of Access center related programs, like MouseKeys and Magnifier etc., is in all likelihood done at the [user-land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space) level (based upon the fact [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373593(v=vs.85).aspx) on the `_MOUSEKEYS struct` says that it is defined in `WinUser.h`). If MouseKeys is enabled I imagine it replaces the keyboard events with Mouse events transparently before sending them to the low level queue via the [`SendInput` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx).

MouseKeys doesn't directly monitor the low-level input queue, it only operates at the window manager level and replaces user keyboard inputs with synthesized mouse movement inputs. The MouseKeys implementation never directly interacts with the input queues at the lowest levels of the OS, which are managed by the kernel itself. Since the `Robot` class is directly inserting the events into the low-level queue it is operating "below" the input hook of the MouseKeys program. MouseKeys receives no key press so it does nothing, but the key press input was placed directly into the low-level queue, so you still see the key press output.

Note that this answer is mostly based on educated speculation, but I think this answer is almost certainly correct. In summation: the MouseKeys program is designed to monitor the user's input, not to monitor low-level input from all sources; when the `Robot` class creates a synthetic input at a low-level MouseKeys is ignorant of the `Robot` class input.

Comment: That clarifies a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking the green checkmark, but only if it answers your question of course. Glad I could help!