# Key Board shortcut for moving mouse cursor (num pad) i.e a,6,2,8... are not working with java robot class

Tags: java, awtrobot

We can use Keyboard shortcut of num pad i.e

```
4-left 6-right 2-down 8-up
```

for scrolling mouse cursor without using mouse.

By enabling

> Control Panel\Ease of Access\Ease of Access Center\Make the mouse easier to use

But it is not working with java robot class - it simply **prints** number i.e 4/6/2/8 on screen.

Any idea what might be the problem?

Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
class MoveCursor 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            Robot r=new Robot();
             r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD4);
             r.delay(4000);
             r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD4);
        } catch (AWTException ex) {
```

Logger.getLogger(MoveCursor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

Comment: This might help, if not a duplicate question: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40942786/do-java-awt-robot-and-java-awt-event-keyevent-support-mousekeys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation states that the `java.awt.Robot` (see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class "generates inputs in the platforms native input queue".

MouseKeys don't operate on that same level (they literally just replace keystrokes with mouse movement operations).

So because MouseKeys don't monitor the native input queue that `java.awt.Robot` adds to, it can't replace the events with mouse movements.

So in short the conclusion is you can not combine `java.awt.Robot` class with mouse keys.

---

However, the `java.awt.Robot` class does offer other functionality you can use for controlling the mouse, namely the the `#mouseMove` function: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#mouseMove-int-int-

Comment: Thank you Sir So what is an easy way to scoll mouse using java

Comment: Well the `java.awt.Robot` class also offers functionality to move the mouse: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#mouseMove-int-int-